# This page isn’t working hotandbold.com redirected you too many times

Tags: magento2, backend, .htaccess

My Magento Backend URL is not working and fronted is working Properly.
Backend Url:- http://hotandbold.com/staging/admin_jewellery/
Fronted Url:- http://hotandbold.com/staging/

Can You suggest me, how can we resolve it
[image]

Comment: Url is working maybe browser cache problem try to load in incognito mode.

Comment: We already tried its not working at chrome but its working at mozilla..can u suggest me why this is happened?

Comment: look into that https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/YzvpLaOmVrY

Answer (score 2):

Here is solution

Go to database find table **core_config_data** and search Path value "***web/cookie/cookie_domain***" remove this row and try.

Comment: its's not working

Comment: Thank you so much. I Totally forgot about the cookies.@HafizArslan I added the domain instead of removing it as he said in his answer. I think without the domain it could be auto generated maybe or become dynamic, but it didn't work with me until I added the domain.com in the db filed.